# JavaScript runtime error when instantiating a select2 combo box

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

When I instantiate a select2 combo box `$('.select2-list').select2();` the combo box is successfully created but the following JavaScript runtime error is thrown for each combo box being created.

> Exception was thrown at line 225, column 13 in
>   https://localhost:44318/ProjectName/lib/select2/js/select2.full.js
>   0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: No en

I'm also unable to use different languages when instantiating them `$('.select2-list').select2({ language: 'es'})`.

I use the combo boxes in

```
<select asp-for="SelectedItemIDs" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Items, "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedItemIDs, "Group"))" class="form-control select2-list"></select>
```

I am using jQuery v3.3.1 and Select2 v4.0.12.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that the entire error message?

Comment: @Olian04 Yes, from the select2.full.js file in the callDep function, it throws it from `throw new Error('No ' + name);` so "en" is the name of the property that it can't find.